# Loading jQuery prints "loading" on page

Tags: jquery

***Update:** Thanks for the comments, although the fix didn't work. Even when I do not include kjquery.js at all the loading message still prints. I'm really at a loss here, if you have any more suggestions please let me know!*

When I include jQuery the word "loading" prints at the end of the page after all content. I have tried to load it from my own server and from the Google API and found the same result both times.

Here's the page:
http://kineticaid.com/k/header.php

And here's the code:

```
 <?php
include('inc/functions.php');
include('inc/titles.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/headerstyle.css"></link>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu|Arimo|PT+Sans:700|Droid+Sans|Nobile|Ovo|Corben:700&v2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kjquery.js"></script>

//this is the problem line
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Shadowbox.init();</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="container">

    <div id="top">
        <?php echo $quote." -".$author; ?>
    </div>
```

Obviously I didn't close any tags, but these are in a footer.php file. Both the header and footer files are included in a home.php file that also prints the word "loading" when it loads.

Comment: you have a script error in kjquery.js:  Line 5, missing }

Comment: `kjquery.js` is missing a `)`.

Comment: The "loading" message is certainly not coming from jQuery itself.

Comment: As I've said, it's coming from Shadowbox because of the error in kjquery.js

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){



});
```

And [get Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). You could have found the answer yourself in seconds!

Answer (score 1):

This loading message is generated by ShadowBox lightbox plugin because you have an error in your kjquery.js file at line 5, missing a `)` as Keith comented.

As soon as you fix this error, all should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with different libraries. I tried loading a simple page and received the "loading" message at the bottom of the page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- content for mobile version -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body class="narrow">
   Simple Page
</body>
</html>
```

After searching for a bit, I found a link for an [example that uses mobile swiping](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_swipe_function), and saw that the mobile library also has a style sheet that must be included. (If you try the example and remove the style link, the loading message will appear in the output.)

Include the style sheet before including the scripts and the message goes away.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```